# Hyphenation not working anymore - polyglossia

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia, ubuntu, german

So I am switching from Windows to Ubuntu. I have finally managed to compile the text in Linux (with texstudio - LuaLaTex), only one thing is amiss: nothing is hyphenated anymore. In windows it works as it should, but in Linux it does not. It now looks like this: 
[image]

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[final]{microtype}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchLowercase}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german} 
\begin{document}
Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen Hefezellenkonzentrationen 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you install the language package of TeXLive? It's package `texlive-lang-european`

Comment: I installed it now (via apt-get, tlmgr install does not work, it says package not present in repository) - Still doesn't work.

Comment: It is in general _not_  a good idea using the TeXLive from Ubuntu. Installing the Distribution from TUG.org makes more sense: https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu  works also for TL2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried running your code and it is working with XeLaTeX and LuaLatex on Ubuntu TexStudio  :

> XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
>
> This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
>
> TeXstudio 2.11.2 (hg 6191:c01fb289a5fe)
> Using Qt Version 5.9.1, compiled with Qt 5.7.1 R

If you are running older version try to update.
Result:

[image]

Comment: ahh, I found the problem. There are two installations of Latex and the compiler is using the old one. Thanks!

Comment: You can mark this as answered if using an updated newer version solved your issue.